# Apache Flink - Periodic Checkpoint Restore After Job Cancellation

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink Java Client and submit a job using RemoteStreamEnvironment.
Periodic checkpointing is enabled and is also retained on job cancellation:

```
streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig()
                        .setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

The issue, though, that it's not clear for me how to resume from the latest checkpoint when submitting "the same" job again - Flink generates a new job id randomly and it all starts from the scratch.
I know it's possible via CLI or WEB UI but I need to support this using Java client.

Is there any support for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can restore from checkpoint the same way as you would restore from a savepoint. Flink internally figures out which is which and restores appropriately. [restore from savepoint doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/#resuming-from-savepoints)

You can use the rest endpoint from java to submit your job along with the checkpoint. You can find the exact details here (Check for the version of flink you are using) - [rest doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/#resuming-from-savepoints)

> /jars/:jarid/run

Use the savepointPath in the body for submitting either savepoint or checkpoint.